# How can I trace the wires of a circuit?

Tags: electrical, switch

I have a switch on my bedroom wall that I believe is used to control the outlet on the same wall. However, the outlet has never worked, and the switch doesn't even seem to be connected to the wires in the wall correctly. How can I trace back the switch or outlet to the panel, or along the inside of the wall to verify that the relationship between switch and wall is even accurate in the first place. I would like to avoid removing the wall as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one device would be to use a multimeter. They have something called a continuity tester, whereby you take the two leads. the one end gets pressed against the one end of the wire, and the other end goes to the other end. if there is a connection, then the multimeter will either show on screen of buzz. ... the real problem is to run a temp wire all the way from  the one end of your wall switch to the other end being tested. (that is just to effectively extend the length of your test leads of the multimeter.
[image]

Comment: So this would confirm whether the switch and the outlet are connected! Thanks.

Comment: yes. this would, however you would need to place the prong of the tester on one end of the switch circuit and the live portion of the outlet... (PS. you do this with the power completely off!)

Comment: I was thinking I could plug in an extension cord or two-prong radio power cord. Power off, of course!