# No power to room

Tags: wiring

Left heater plugged in drying floor all night. Woke up to no power in room and no breaker kicked. Can't figure out what happened. Checked plug in and shows hot and ground reversed but don't no how. Worked fine before last night. Breaker is good. Any help please

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident you can [work safely](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/47613/2815) with lethal voltages and have [suitable tools](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/90038/2815), you could turn off the breaker and open up the outlet the heater was plugged into and check for damage caused by local overheating due to a bad connection. If there is any evidence of burning/melting/scorching, it is sensible to replace all damaged parts. If wire or it's insulation is damaged, I would trim off the damaged portion and, if necessary extend the wire using a pigtail or splice/butt connector rated for the voltage and current.

Otherwise you may need to [trace the circuit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/58902/2815) back towards the breaker and check for correct polarity at each outlet or junction box on the circuit until you find the fault.

It is worth turning the relevant circuit breaker off and on again. However you should still investigate the ground-hot reversal which is a serious safety hazard.

If there are any GFCIs anywhere on the circuit you could try resetting them but a tripped GFCI would not explain the ground-hot reversal.