# One light switch controlling multiple lights

Tags: electrical

So my husband and I bought an older house (1956). After we moved in, we noticed that if we turn off a certain switch in the kitchen, we can't turn on the lights in the hall, bathroom, or bedrooms. This is very annoying because we have to either leave that switch on (which means one set of kitchen lights are on 24/7), or turn it off and not have lights in the above mentioned rooms. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved? Do you have a way to test for voltage? We don't have remote X-ray vision to see inside the walls of your house...

Comment: Likely mis-wired.  Frankly you should A) hire an electrician B) find a friend or relative with enough Electricical knowledge to locate the issue.  Sniffing this issue out is not something scoped as a beginner project, even with help from the Internet.

Comment: Could be a simple wire fix or a complicated re-wiring job. As @ThreePhaseEel said, a picture of the offending switch box could be the key.

Comment: Could be serious, could be something simple.  You need a good professional electrician: hire him or her to give the house a good checkup.

Comment: PROBABLY a simple fix! Defiantly not serious. We are a DIY site for the 2 above that say call an electrician, comment when you can help really. I would bet that a DIY type replaced one or more switches without paying attention to how they were wired, a common hot was put in the wrong place (or as RME stated a switched neutral).

Comment: @Help Ed Beals comment is probably exactly what you have going on. Your Hot wire that was supposed to tie in with a wire nut and go to the other rooms was most likely connected to the switched side of that switch. A VERY SIMPLE FIX for this! Turn off your circuit breaker (or remove fuse) . Open up that switch cover pull your switch out far enough to expose the wires for a photograph. Take that picture and post it.

Comment: @EdBeal Wish I could plus you ten just for the common sense in your comment! This is most likely a simple issue: a continuation run was supposed to be connected to the LINE side and a DIY'er or a 'professional' in training connected it to the Switched Load side.

Answer (score 2):

I read your question and the many comments and answers. There is one answer [retired Master Electricians] and one comment [ Ed Beal's ] that I would advise to consider as they provide valuable insight to what could be wrong and specifically ed's comment that there is most likely a simple solution for your problem that you yourself can solve with a little knowledge of being safe with electrical wires and some direction. I add my own answer here to assist you as well.

I think this is what happened: someone rewired that specific switch and instead of placing the continuation wire in the wire nut on the supply line in, they placed it on the Load side of the switch. I will have a diagram of what I believe you have. And what you need to do. There is a SIMPLE FIX for this issue.

In regards to some other comments:
Being as your house was built in the 1950's and not the 1930's I do not believe you have switched neutrals. The reason this was banned was that people could be electrocuted just by installing a light bulb. I am not saying this is impossible but I do believe it was codified in the 1930's. A Big clue will be that the white wires are connected to the switch terminals. If this is the case you might want to have the whole house electrical system brought up to date for the sake of your safety.

What I believe is your issue with he solution below it :

[image: Switch Wiring]

Comment: Exactly what I think has happened, possibly more switches but the basic drawing is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

> **Any ideas how to fix this?**

The general approach for sorting out this type of wiring misconfiguration is

1. Phone an electrician. Or
2. Purchase [appropriate equipment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/90038/2815), study [how to use it safely](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/47613/2815), Turn off the breakers and [trace the wiring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/58902/2815) to map out exactly all the affected wires, cables, switches, lamps, junction boxes, outlets and other elements. You may find it helpful to physically label the wires to distinguish between multiple wires of the same colour at each location. Once you fully understand the existing configuration, formulate a plan for altering the known configuration to the desired configuration. This might for example involve planning to replace some wiring in the walls or run new wiring through the walls, this may mean making further plans for opening the walls and modifying plans based on what is found inside them. You might need to install different switches or additional switches - you therefore may need to check box-loadings and plan for additional boxes in the wall.

To obtain more specific help here (for plan 2 above) you should ideally turn off the breakers, open up all the switches, outlets, junction boxes etc and carefully photograph the existing wiring (without disconnecting any), pay attention to focus and lighting for your photographs, you may need to take several photos of each area from different angles and/or push the wiring around so that nothing is obscured. Make a well-labelled clear diagram and a careful explanation of what happens now and what you want to happen instead (this last part you already have).

The above may seem daunting. That's because it is a general approach. With a bit more information, a simple fix may become apparent.

Comment: I won't drive by your answer as some do.  Just because something does not work like it should is not a reason to jump to the phone as the first approach. This could be as simple as the continuation run was connected to the load side of the switch instead of the line side. I will say the parts about how to take things out, photograph them for posting is probably the most helpful and perhaps we should have that for use as a guide on DIY Stack as a quick link or pop up info when people are posting questions regarding electrical.

Answer (score 1):

I am reading your question and I can only think of two situations that this might occur.

You have two switches wired in series with each other. Meaning you have a the source conductor attached to the first switch that turns on your kitchen area then that switch leg is attached to one side of your other switch which turns on your other lights.

The other situation would be that you are switching the neutral on the switch that controls your kitchen switch, and that neutral is common to the other switch. This is fairly common in houses built in the 1950's and don't be surprised if the other switch is switching its neutral also. If this is the case you may need to have these switches rewired so the neutral is no longer being switched. I can't tell you how to correct it since there are various methods of rewiring and it would require someone with a better knowledge of how your house was wired. Probably a local professional.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: I agree it is probably a simple (very simple case) where a DIY person installed new switches and wired one backwards. A few minutes mapping the switches and a photo of the wiring I am sure. Close to a dozen sparkys or DIY sparkys on this site can point you to the correct wiring solution, can you turn off a circuit breaker, unscrew a few screws you probably can fix this.